# wanted to keep the top version which is soacs12.2.1.3 and delete the rest

Tags: shell, unix

```
[sean@testserver downloadBinaries]$ ls -ltr
total 8
drwxrwxr-x 2 sean sean 4096 Jun 30  2018 soacs12.2.1.3
drwxrwxr-x 2 sean sean 4096 Jun 30  2018 soacs12.2.1.2
drwxrwxr-x 2 sean sean 4096 Jun 30  2018 soacs12.2.1.1
```

From the above i wanted to keep soacs12.2.1.3 and delete other two directories using a shell script command

Comment: And what have you tried? Have you looked into `sort`? GNU's implementation has an option for version sorting afaik

Comment: Use `-v` in `ls` from man page `-v     natural sort of (version) numbers within text`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
ls -vd soacs12.2.1.* | sed \$d | xargs rm -rf
```

It deletes all files in the current directory with name starting `soacs12.2.1.` ignoring the highest one in natural sorting.

Be sure to backup your files before running it, just in case if it wasn't what you wanted to do.

Comment: the problem is it removes other directories as well

Comment: @RijeshParambath Ok if thats a problem I edited my answer and now it should work.